# Best way to connect classes

Tags: php, class, oop, architecture, construct

So, I'm not using any framework, developing a system on MVC architecture using PHP and have several components. One of them is Sanitize, for filtering vars.

The problem that I came into is, how to better sanitize the vars?

Easier to show in an example:

```
class Sanitize {
    public function sanitizeString($string) {
        return filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    }
}
```

Then I want this class to be executed on models and controllers and well, almost all files. To don't write everytime $sanitize = new Sanitize; I'm used to add a public __construct function that will create a sanitize var.

```
private $sanitize;
public function __construct() {
    $sanitize = new Sanitize();
}
```

Then I just call it in my function using

```
$string = $this->sanitize->sanitizeString($string);
```

The problem is that I'm a lil bit paranoid, so I connect a sanitize class automatically in every single class, specially models, to sanitize data when it goes into DB. So here happens something like a recursion and there are a var that is created over and over. For example a controller will create a sanitize class using construct. Then in a method I will create new class in model User, and User class also creates a sanitize in it, as well as some data from Cookies and Access classes, both from which creates sanitize in it.

So I called 1 method, but it created 4 duplicates of sanitize, some even without a need...

What's the best practise? Am I doing it right?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're paranoid, you should use a well-supported framework and benefit from the shared paranoia of the community's security experts.

Comment: You can simply create Santize as a static class. Call it like `Sanitize::string($string)`. I'd avoid calling the function `sanitizeString`, for de-deduplication. `Sanitize::sanitizeString($string)` seems silly.

Comment: Don't sanitize data on input. _Validate_ data on input. Save it "as is" in the database (using prepared statements, of course, to protect you from sql injections). Only sanitize data on _output_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fast scratch of one solution:

```
<?php
interface ISanitizedValue {
    public function value();
}

class CSanitizedLogin implements ISanitizedValue {
    private $_rawValue;

    public function __construct($value){
        $this->_rawValue = $value;
    }

    public function value(){
        // sanitizing
    }
}

class CSomeClass {
    // force to use ISanitizedValue
    public function __construct(ISanitizedValue $login){}
}

$login = new CSanitizedLogin($_GET['login']);
$example1 = new CSomeClass($login);
$example2 = new CSomeClass($login);
?>
```